# How to show a list below an input test?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I show a list (like Google does with keywords) below an input text?

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is perfectly clear to me and at least three other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [*jQuery UI autocomplete*](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use it's a concept called autocomplete. jQuery has one at his [UI](http://jqueryui.it/demos/autocomplete). Now in [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_form_autocomplete.asp) you can use autocomplete on fields but only with words that had already been typed and submited by the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<input autocomplete="on">
```

Comment: "Note (2010-06-23): This plugin is deprecated and not developed anymore. Its successor is part of jQuery UI"

Comment: Thanks didn't realized that. I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without any real specifics to the question, or the other technologies you're using, you could check out [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) for making a suggestion list for an input box.